# AngularJS Diferença ng-show e ng-if

Tags: angularjs

Qual a diferença entre utilizar **ng-if** e **ng-show/ng-hide** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `ng-show`/`ng-hide`

Ambos trabalham com a propriedade CSS `display`. Se a expressão do `ng-show` retornar `false` ou `ng-hide` retornar `true`, então o elemento será ocultado usando `display: none`. Nos casos contrários de ambas diretivas, o valor da propriedade `display` *não é* alterado.

Isto significa, por exemplo, se você *já* tiver um `display: none` no seu elemento, este valor não é alterado.

Exemplo:

```
<!-- Vai ocultar -->
<div ng-show="false"></div>

<!-- Vai ocultar -->
<div ng-hide="true"></div>

<!-- Vai continuar com o display atual -->
<div ng-show="true"></div>

<!-- Vai continuar com o display atual -->
<div ng-hide="false"></div>
```

*Na verdade,* você vai reparar que o Angular usa uma classe `.ng-hide` cuja única propriedade é `display: none`, invés de definir um CSS inline no elemento.

## `ng-if`

Remove o elemento do DOM quando a expressão retornar `false`, e recoloca ele no DOM quando retornar `true`.

Exemplo:

```
<!-- Vai deixar o elemento do DOM -->
<div ng-if="true"></div>

<!-- Vai remover o elemento do DOM -->
<div ng-if="false"></div>
```

Comment: Muito boa a explicação cara, simples e direta! Valeu